# Como exibir todos os itens contidos em uma tupla listados em uma coluna?

Tags: python, tuple

No estudo de tuplas me coloquei um desafio para a seguinte tupla:

```
casa = (
    ('porta', 'janela', ('parede', 'quadro')),
    ('estante', 'mesa', 'cadeira', ('livros', 'cadernos', 'canetas'))
)
```

O que fazer para obter o seguinte resultado em forma de coluna?

- porta
- janela
- parede
- quadro
- estante
- mesa
- cadeira
- livros
- cadernos
- canetas

Tentar resolver esse pequeno desafio já foi extremamente válido, pois me fez testar diversas funções e descobrir muitas outras coisas, porém ainda sem conseguir o resultado desejado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
casa = (
    ('porta', 'janela', ('parede', 'quadro')),
    ('estante', 'mesa', 'cadeira', ('livros', 'cadernos', 'canetas'))
)


def varretupla(tupla):
    for item in tupla:
        if type(item) is str:
            print(item)
        if type(item) is tuple:
            varretupla(item)


varretupla(casa)
```

Trata-se de uma função recursiva. Criei uma condição em que se caso o item fosse uma tupla, a função de varrer tupla seria chamada novamente.
Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Sensacional. Muito obrigado. Vou me aprofundar no tema já.